# Calculating Variance and Variance% in Dax

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

In my PBIX File, I have measures that calculate Revenue, COGS, Gross Margin etc.

```
Revenue = Sum(Amt)
```

More measures that calculate value for Last year Revenue_LY, COGS_LY and GM_LY.

```
Revenue_LY = CALCULATE (
  [Revenue],
  FILTER (
       ALL ( 'Date' ),
            'Date'[FinYear]= MAX ( 'Date'[FinYear] ) - 1 && 'Date'[FinPeriod] = max('Date'[FinPeriod])
    )
 )
```

Now I need variance and variance% measures for each which compare data against last year and budget. The amount of measures is just getting too many.

```
Revenue_CY-LY = CALCULATE([Revenue],KEEPFILTERS(Versions[VersionCode] = "Act")) - CALCULATE([Revenue_LY],KEEPFILTERS(Versions[VersionCode] = "Act"))

Revenue_CY-LY% = IF([Revenue_CY-LY] < 0, -1, 1) *
                IF(
                    ABS(DIVIDE([Revenue_CY-LY],[Revenue])) > 99.9, 
                        "n/a",
                    ABS(DIVIDE([Revenue_CY-LY],[Revenue])*100)
            )
```

Is there a way to summarize the measures used. I don't want to create individual measures of each variance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can create a dynamic measure.

First create `Revenue`, `COGS`, `Gross Margin`, etc. measures.

```
Revenue = SUM([Amt])
COGS = SUM([Cost])
Gross Margin = [Revenue] - [COGS]
...
```

Then you create a table with one row for each of your measures:

```
My Measures = DATATABLE("My Measure", STRING, {{"Revenue"}, {"COGS"}, {"Gross Margin"}})
```

The names don't need to align with your actual measures, but they will be displayed so make them presentable.

Then you create a measure on that table which will dynamically be the same as the selected row in the table:

```
Selected Measure = SWITCH(SELECTEDVALUE('My Measures'[My Measure], BLANK()), "Revenue", [Revenue], "COGS", [COGS], "Gross Margin", [Gross Margin], BLANK())
```

Next you go and create all the complicated time-intelligence measures using the `[Selected Measure]` as the base:

```
Dynamic_LY = CALCULATE (
  [Selected Measure],
  FILTER (
      ALL ( 'Date' ),
            'Date'[FinYear]= MAX ( 'Date'[FinYear] ) - 1 && 'Date'[FinPeriod] = max('Date'[FinPeriod])
    )
 )
```

And then you can do `[Dynamic_CY-LY]` and `[Dynamic_CY-LY %]` in a similar manner to the ones in your question, replacing references to the `[Revenue]` measure with references to the dynamic measures.

Now you can either use a slicer on the `'My Measures'[My Measure]` column to dynamically change every instance of `[Dynamic_CY-LY]` and the other dynamic measures, or you can add a filter on each visualisation to filter `'My Measures'[My Measure]`.

It might be that you'd also like to have a default value for `[Selected Measure]` instead of defaulting to `BLANK()`; just put that in last position in the `SWITCH()` function.